# verilog register assignment comes out as XXXXXXX in simulation

Tags: verilog, variable-assignment

```
input [6:0] load,
 input up,
 input down,
output reg [6:0] currentvalue
);

  reg [6:0] state, nextup, nextdown;

initial
    begin
        state = load;
    end
```

Hey guys! I'm trying to make a module where I receive a 7bit input (load) and assign the input value to a 7bit register (state). When I run this code through the ISE simulator, I get  XXXXXXXX for the register value 'state.' Other than that, the module seem to be working properly, and there are no errors.
I tried the following instead of my original code to see if it would work.

```
initial
     begin
       state = 7'd35;
     end
```

And it did work. I just have a vague idea that there is a problem with my assigning the input value to a register, but I haven't been able to figure out exactly how to solve this. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: You show only one effective line of code with 'it does not work'. Show more code, also specify where, how often, it does not work. More important find Verilog modules of experienced coders and see how it looks like. Verilog is **not like C**, It requires a totally different coding style.

Answer (score 1):

All 4-state variables in verilog are initialized to 'x'.

The `initial` block is there for initializing variables before simulation starts.  So, in the first version `state = load` you just assigned 'x' value of 'load' to `state` (which already was 'x').

In the second variant you assigned a numeric value to the `state`. Which is what the `initial` block is for.

In simulation all main actions happen in the `always` blocks which your module is lacking. And you would need to write a test bench code to generate some stimuli for you your module inputs to see any reaction.